# How can I create form object for the update action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns

There is a form object which allows creating an object with associations.
This main problem is associations update. I really don't know how to extend this without tons of `each` and conditions.
What is the most convenient way to extend this class for updating object?

```
module Company
  class JobForm
    include ActiveModel::Model

    attr_accessor :title, :body, :city, :start_date, :attachments, 
                          :requirements, :company
    attr_reader :object

    validates :title, :body, :start_date, :city, presence: true

    def save
      persist! if valid?
    end

    private

    def persist!
      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        save_job
        save_attachments
        save_requirements
      end
      object
    end

    def save_job
      @object = company.jobs.create( 
          # attributes.. ..)
    end

    def save_attachments
      return unless attachments&.present?
      attachments.each do |attacment_attributes|
        object.attachments.create(attacment_attributes)
      end
    end

    def save_requirements
      return unless requirements&.present?
      object.requirements.destroy_all
      requirements.each do |requirement_attributes|
        object.requirements.create(requirement_attributes)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: you don't have to model the associations to reflect the actual model(s) you're eventually going to  create or update. Just create additional attributes in your form object, and then do all the persisted logic in another method, flow object, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked about the most convenient way to implement updating in custom form objects... but custom form object is not a convenient way to work with forms in Rails.

There are some handy gems which help to build complex forms. One of them is `reform`. Look at the Populator section http://trailblazer.to/gems/reform/populator.html.

If you work with collection usually you have to match incomming params and associated objects manually in right order, look at the following example

```
collection :songs,
  populator: ->(fragment:, **) {
    # find out if incoming song is already added.
    item = songs.find { |song| song.id == fragment["id"].to_i }

    item ? item : songs.append(Song.new)
  }
```

If you already have associated model - you return it from populator and it will be updated with incomming parameters. If you don't have it - you build a new model and it will be created with incomming parameters...

Comment: Respectfully, the assertion that it's not a convenient way... is quite a stretch, imo. It's far superior to working with nested attributes, and you don't need yet another gem, and dsl for building a form. You just create a class, include ActiveModel::Model, and probably ActiveModel::Validations, then set it up with attr_accessor and the form will see it just like a typical model, so you can use form_for helpers, etc. I find them quite a bit more convenient, myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilise the feature of mass assignment, where if an object with a one-to-many association is instantiated with a params hash, and that hash has a key for the association, Rails will call the `<association_name>_attributes=`

So you can define that method on your form object class:

```
def attachments_attributes=(attributes)
  @attachments ||= []
  attributes.each do |_, attachment_params|
    attachment = @attachments.find {|a| a.id.to_s == attachment_params[:id]}
    attachment ? attachment.assign_attributes(document_params) : @attachments.push(Attachment.new(attachment_params))
  end
end
```